# Why "Follow symbol under cursor" does not work in Qt Creator for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, g++, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator under Mac osx, but "Follow symbol under cursor" option, to allow me to jump for class and methods' definitions, does not really work... it only works for local symbols. neither does "Switch between method declaration/definition"

Any ideas?

Thanks much for any thought.
Lior

Answer (score 0):

First off, which version of Qt Creator are you using?

There is a Qt Creator 1.3 <strike>release candidate</strike> final release (1.3) out now that you might want to try: <strike>http://qt.nokia.com/developer/qt-creator-1.3-preview</strike>  [Qt Website Download Section](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As @badcat said, ensure that you have the most recent version.

Other than that, when you have problems following a "symbol under cursor" it could mean 1 of 2 things.

1)  I would check that you have your project appropriately constructed so that it has all the include and source files that it needs.

2)  This is more rare, but check that you have function definitions in header files and that they are included properly by your source files.  As opposed to what you may ask?  We have a project here where, instead of include files, functions are defined in .cc files, and extern statements are used so that other files have access to them. (It's legacy code)  In such a case, Qt Creator doesn't know how to find anything because files are only aware of each other while linking and have no other way to see each other.